# Generic in Java throwing errors when methods are defined

Tags: java, generics

I am learning Generics in Java. For that, I tried out a simple LinkedList like that.

```
class Node {
  private int age;
  private String name;
  private Node next;

  public Node(int age, String name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.next = null;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public Node getNext() {
    return this.next;
  }

  public void setNext(Node next) {
    this.next = next;
  }
}

class LinkedList<T> {
  private T head;
  private T current;

  public LinkedList() {
    head = null;
    current = null;
  }

  public void append(T x) {
    if (head == null) {
      head = x;
      current = x;
    }
    else {
      current.setNext(x);
      current = x;
    }
  }

  public T getAt(int index) {
    T ptr = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
      ptr = ptr.getNext();
    }
    return ptr;
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Node> list = new LinkedList<Node>();
    list.append(new Node(39, "John"));
    list.append(new Node(43, "Josh"));
    Node x = list.getAt(1);
    System.out.println(String.format("%d, %s", x.getAge(), x.getName()));
  }
}
```

But I get this error, while all the methods do exist in the Node class. What mistake am I doing?

```
LinkedList.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
      current.setNext(x);
             ^
  symbol:   method setNext(T)
  location: variable current of type T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class LinkedList
LinkedList.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
      ptr = ptr.getNext();
               ^
  symbol:   method getNext()
  location: variable ptr of type T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class LinkedList
2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `current` is of type `T`, you can't call methods of the `Node` class (such as `setNext()`) on `current`, since `T` can be substituted by any class when you instantiate your `LinkedList`.

Your `Node` class shouldn't be the generic type argument of `LinkedList`. A `LinkedList` should always be made of `Node`s. The type of the data stored in each `Node` should be a generic type.

```
class Node<T> {
  private T data;
  private Node next;

  public Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
```

And the `LinkedList` should contain `Node<T>` nodes:

```
class LinkedList<T> {
  private Node<T> head;
  private Node<T> current;
}
```

Comment: OK, that is the preferred method of course, but still why do I get errors in that code? I see nothing wrong there.

Comment: @MetallicPriest you are trying to call a method of `Node` class on an instance whose type is the generic type parameter `T`. That's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is unable to understand T type. You have used `t.setNext()` , however it is isn't present in T definition unless actually used. I might sound a bit confusing here but try this:

Create an Interface `Contract` having setNext and getNext method.
Implement Node extending above interface. `Node implements Contract`.
In Linked List change generics to `T extends Contract`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `hasNext` for any given generic `T`, so the code doesn't compile

You'd have to make sure that the LinkedList only holds Node classes or its subtypes

```
class LinkedList<T extends Node>
```

But note: That T is not the same as the generic stored within the nodes, so this seems better

```
class LinkedList<T> {
    Node<T> head;
```

Answer (score 1):

`private T current;` is a generic type and you are calling `setNext` and `getNext` on it. How come `T` know that it always have these methods? That's the reason it's not working.

Hence, you need to ensure that your generic type T knows that it has `setNext` and `getNext` methods.

Hence the fix is:

`T extends NodeAbstract` in class definition where NodeAbstract is the interface declaring signature of these methods. now this ensures that anything T gets is always going to have these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

You must make `Node<T>` and `LinkedList<Node>`.

```
public void append(T x) { // Here x is of Type T
if (head == null) {
  head = x;
  current = x; //Assigning x to current, current is also of Type T
}
else {
  current.setNext(x); // T.setNext is not defined! Because T can be a String/Integer/whatever. They do not have setNext method
  current = x;
}
}
```